# Performance of a deep learning model on the validation dataset

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I trained a DNN on a dataset of speech embeddings. The validation accuracy during the training is 99.5% then I stopped the training and save the best model. When I did the inference on the test dataset the accuracy is 91% which is acceptable. The problem is when did the inference on the validation set the accuracy should be approximately the same but in my case, it is 84%. Can someone give me an explanation for this?

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_name))
model.eval()
model.to(device)

intentSet, subIntentSet = test_data.getsets()
actionSet, objectSet, locationSet = subIntentSet

correct_test = []
for i, d in enumerate(test_set_generator):
    feat, label = d
    print('Iter %d (%d/%d)' % (i, i * batch_size, len(test_data)), end='\r')
    
    z_eval = model(feat.float().to(device))
    pred = [torch.max(z.detach().cpu(), dim=1)[1] for z in z_eval]
    if mode == 'multitask':
        combined_pred = [(actionSet[pred[0][l]], objectSet[pred[1][l]], locationSet[pred[2][l]]) for l in
                         range(len(pred[0]))]
        pred_test = torch.tensor([intentSet.index(p) if p in intentSet else -1 for p in combined_pred])
    else:
        pred_test = pred[0]

    correct_test.append(np.array(pred_test == label[0], dtype=float))

acc_test = (np.mean(np.hstack(correct_test)))
print("The accuracy on test set is %f" % acc_test)

correct_valid = []
for i, d in enumerate(valid_set_generator):
    print('Iter %d (%d/%d)' % (i, i * batch_size, len(valid_data)), end='\r')
    feat, label = d
    a_eval = model(feat.float().to(device))
 
    pred = [torch.max(a.detach().cpu(), dim=1)[1] for a in a_eval]
    if mode == 'multitask':
        combined_pred = [(actionSet[pred[0][l]], objectSet[pred[1][l]], locationSet[pred[2][l]]) for l in
                         range(len(pred[0]))]
        pred_test = torch.tensor([intentSet.index(p) if p in intentSet else -1 for p in combined_pred])
    else:
        pred_test = pred[0]

    correct_valid.append(np.array(pred_test == label[0], dtype=float))
acc_val = (np.mean(np.hstack(correct_valid)))
print("The accuracy on the validation set is %f" % acc_val)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question fully, but one thing that caught me previously (in Keras) was my test set was not a multiple of my batch size so some samples were passed through more than once. Stratified k-fold cross validation and taking averages might help? Also look at the class distribution of test/train/validation. Are they the same? Is there any imbalance?

Comment: I can summarize my question as there is a large gap between " The validation accuracy during training and  the validation accuracy during inference on the same validation dataset"

Comment: What is your validation code? Are you doing inference with eval model on?

Comment: @Ivan I edited my question and add the code can you have a look at it.

Comment: Welcome to SO; this is a Q&A site, so there is *absolutely* no reason to begin your posts with "*I have a question and need an explanation*" (we know, otherwise you would not be here - edited out).